# Dynamically Rendering a React component from an Import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to be able to render components that are created on the fly. A simple example.

**Dynamic Data**

```
import * as Positions from '../../../Positions/index' //Contains the imports

const data = [
    {
        name: 'Hand Give',
        icon: 'hand_give',
        code:1,
        selected: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Hand Receive',
        icon: 'hand_receive',
        code:2,
        selected: false
    }
];

 ... other stuff....

render (){
    return (
        <div>
            {
                data.map((item, index) => {
                    const Pos = Positions[item['icon']];
                    console.info(Pos); //outputs function hand_give ()...
                    return <div key={item.code} >
                            <Pos />
                        </div>
                    }
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Positions/index.js**

```
export hand_give from './hand_give';
export hand_receive from './hand_receive';
```

**A typical import from Positions/index**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class hand_give extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return ( <div>
                     <h2>jamie</h2>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

I believe this should render the component and I'm miffed as why it doesn't

Comment: This looks like it should work to me too, what does the compiled JSX look like?

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: No errors no. The compiled html outsides as `<pos></pos>` so obviously its not executing somehow. Whats weird is, if I console log `console.info(<pos />)` it will output it as a react comp

Comment: `export hand_gives from './hand_give';` This export should be `hand_receive`? One of your icons - hand_receive is not having any component.

Comment: Yes, good spot, although that was just me manually writting that. So sadly its not the error